# Foreach in an array

Tags: php, arrays, json

Is there anyway to use a foreach in an array so I can get all the rides into a table and then encode it to json? So I can decode it in a game with lua?
how can I put it all in an array and then encode it and decode it later wirth lua in the game.

```
    $getRides = $db->prepare('select * from `Rides`');
    $getRides->execute();
    $values = $getRides->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$array = array(
    array("Name",foreach($values as $key){ $key->Name; }),
    array("Active",$values->Active)
);
print_r($array)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely read some information about foreach statement and php loops in general.

**[PHP: foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)**, **[PHP Control Structures](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php)**

Corrent code:

```
$getRides = $db->prepare('select * from `Rides`');
$getRides->execute();
$values = $getRides->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$array = array();
foreach($values as $value) {
    $array[] = array(
        'Name' => $value->Name,
        'Active' => $value->Active
    );
}

print_r($array)
```